# grep/sed/awk out everything before a certain line

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, grep

My command has the following raw output

```
Wi-Fi:

      Software Versions:
          CoreWLAN: 2.1.1 (211.3)
          CoreWLANKit: 1.0.1 (101.1)
          Menu Extra: 7.0.1 (701.2)
          configd plug-in: 7.1.1 (711.1)
          System Profiler: 7.0 (700.3)
          IO80211 Family: 4.1.1 (411.1)
          WiFi Diagnostics: 1.0.1 (101.1)
          AirPort Utility: 5.5.3 (553.20)
      Interfaces:
        en1:
          Card Type: AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0xD6)
          Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.18)
          MAC Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          Locale: FCC
          Country Code: US
          Supported PHY Modes: 802.11 a/b/g/n
          Supported Channels: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140, 149, 153, 157, 161, 165
          Wake On Wireless: Supported
          AirDrop: Supported
          Status: Connected
         **Current Network Information:**
            PEETS:
              PHY Mode: 802.11g
              BSSID: 00:17:c5:0c:85:50
              Channel: 6
              Country Code: US
              Network Type: Infrastructure
              Security: None
              Signal / Noise: -52 dBm / -89 dBm
              Transmit Rate: 54
          Other Local Wi-Fi Networks:
            hpsetup:
              PHY Mode: 802.11b
              BSSID: ba:78:b7:86:78:69
              Channel: 6
              Network Type: Computer-to-Computer
              Security: None
              Signal / Noise: -90 dBm / -92 dBm
            yogurtland:
              PHY Mode: 802.11g
              BSSID: 0c:d5:02:7b:ce:5b
              Channel: 11
              Network Type: Infrastructure
              Security: WEP
              Signal / Noise: -72 dBm / -92 dBm
```

However, I only want the information past "Current Network Information:". Counting the lines before does not work as that information is variable.  Also, the pound signs were put in by me. Please ignore them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using `awk`:

```
awk '/Current Network Information/,0' INPUT_FILE
```

#### Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/Current Network Information/,$p' INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: +1: Interesting. I wasn't aware that 'awk' handles ranges like that, but POSIX [awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) does, and so does GNU 'awk'.  I thought it might be a GNU extension.  One lives and learns; long live SO.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I second that `long live SO` :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. Where did you find the range stuff for awk. I couldnt find it on the man page

Comment: It's just a regular range `/StartRegex/,/EndRegex/`. The only difference is that our `EndRegex` is a `0` which means `false`. So this one-liner will match our `/StartRegex/` and continue to the end of the file because `0` is always `false` and `EndRegex` never matches. :-)

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for explaining it. Just out of curiosity, how would you do it the other way. start at the beginning and end when you reach current netwrok information.

Comment: Hmm… for the other way we can do something like this `awk 'NR==1,/Current Network Information/' filename` though I haven't tested it. It means match `line number 1` and start printing till you see the `EndRegex`.

Answer (score 3):

```
yourcommand | sed -e '1,/Current Network Information/d'
```

the `1,/Current Network Information/` is the address specifier for the sed `d` command

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/Current Network Information:/,$!d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk approach:

```
awk '/Current Network Information:/ { shouldPrint = 1 } shouldPrint'
```